# Modifying innerHTML of an element created with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Basically, I have a div that I insert content into with innerHTML. A segment of the HTML inserted is:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><span class="bold" id="timer">00:00:00:0</span></p>
```

This is a timer that should increment using a setTimeout. Later, I call the following function to modify the timer  block:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = output;
```

When checking the innerHTML property with Firebug or an alert, the innerHTML of the span element is incrementing (e.g. it will say "00:00:10:6" or "00:01:01:4"). However, the page does not reflect the changes; the browser still shows 00:00:00:0.

I tried placing the span directly on the page as opposed to through modifying the div with innerHTML, and only then does it work. Is there anyway to make it work with innerHTML on the div?

EDIT: The page is -----
Try using Firebug or the Chrome console to check the follow:

```
document.getElementById('bunny-timer').innerHTML
```

EDIT 2: URL removed.

Comment: works fine for me using only innerHTML using FF 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code, my best guess is that you're accidentally creating duplicate ids, and the element you're seeing is different than the one you're inspecting.

Comment: According to Firebug, I do not have any duplicate IDs on the page.

Comment: My apologies, you were right. The other element with the ID was hidden, so I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers. As you're already using jQuery quite a lot, why not play with their timer functions? They seem to be quite well-made.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely looks useful, but I don't think the timer is the real problem. I figure it has something to do with the DOM not recognizing the span element or something.

Comment: what suggests he's using jQuery at all?  if he were using it at all getelementbyId would be the first thing to go.  I agree its a good idea tho